# Bootstrap site not displaying certain values in modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site using Bootstrap. I have a modal which shows a preview of user entered values. The modal works except for two fields, title and author. The fields get the values correctly, but they do not display inside the modal. The problem statement is this:

```
    <h1 ><span id="previewNewstreamTitle">Default Title</span><br> by <span id="previewJournalistName">Portland Helmich</span>

  <br> <small>An Audio &amp; Video Newstream</small></h1>
```

Like I said, the rest of the modal, and the script that updates the modal values, all work as intended so I won't post the entire code here. Only this h1 block has issues. The ids update to the correct value but do not display inside the modal

Comment: Not enough information is given to answer the question, i need to know what your css and js look like, try linking a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xckznLo2/

Comment: I don't think it will run because the box values are null.

Comment: The JsFiddle you linked does not run at all